# Postfix - forwarding some email addresses to an alias through external SMTP service

Tags: postfix, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to set up a Postfix server on Google Cloud, which blocks outgoing SMTP ports. My problem is that one email address (say `alias@example.com`) needs to be an alias for an external email address (`foo@example2.com`); all emails sent to alias@example.com need to be forwarded to foo@example2.com. I also have other email addresses that simply need to be delivered locally.

I am able to get Postfix to attempt to send all emails to alias@example.com to foo@example2.com using virtual alias mappings, but because SMTP ports are blocked, the connection doesn't go through to example2.com's SMTP server. I want to get Postfix to send these emails through Mailjet on port 2525 so that the connection isn't blocked. Unfortunately, even when `relayhost` is set to `in-v3.mailjet.com:2525`, Postfix doesn't attempt to relay the emails and instead tries to send them directly.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: It's `relayhost`, not `relay_host`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do any relay directive, postfix by default will try to lookup the mx for that domain, so you have to tell postfix to use the a-record provided using brackets, see my relayhost directive below.

```
relayhost = [vps1.domain.com]:26
```

I'm using an off port to get around my ISP blocking smtp, so this forces postfix to go straight to that a-record and connect to send email.